# Visual Studio SharePoint API Code Works on other Computers but not mine

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint

C# Console Application connects to SharePoint 2013 on other machines. I run it on my laptop and I continue to get a 401 Unauthorized error. I am able to connect to the SharePoint through my browser without any problems.

Comment: have you contacted your user system admin this issue is happening because connecting thru your browser.. your dba or admin has setup a system account or a user account that recognizes your credentials probably via PrincipalContext, ActiveDirectory, etc.. on the console application it does not recognize you as the user running the application but it recognizes it as a NetWork app you could try using Impersonation but I would personally not do that.. you need to have your asp.net account / user setup for this to work through your console application..

Comment: you could also ask your network admin if all the working machines have been setup to work based on their individual domain/machinename that's probably what's going on there..[user / computer Accounts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759279%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, it was a workstation issue

Comment: no problem.. but the second link would also benefit you if you wanted to do it that way as well.. glad you resolved your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried running your visual studio application as another user?

Truez

Comment: `-1` This is not what the `OP` is asking this has nothing to do with Visual Studio because the process will not be Launched from the IDE